# Same email address for two users SharePoint Microsoft 365

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have two users with same email address in site's User Information list. One of the user is not active and has been deleted from the active directory. The second user has been added. Both of them have different login names and are external users.

We have a custom solution which uses email address to get user in SharePoint and assigns the permission (Read/Full Control etc) as per data from external system. External system has user email and permission data only.

But since there are two users with same email address, the permission is getting assigned to incorrect user.

I have site collection administrator permission. If I try to edit the user, I can't edit email field.

How can I edit the user email? Or I will have to delete the user from site collection?

Comment: Have you tried to remove both user from the information list and ask the active user to log in?

Comment: I haven't tried to remove the user from the information list because I am not sure how that will affect the list and document library metadata. Is this ok to remove the user which is not active now?

Comment: It is fine to remove user from user information list. Next time the user access the site collection, SharePoint will add him to the list.